# mix-blend-mode appears to not be working in edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode
says it is supported but
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode
None of these examples work for me when I open the link in edge and they work fine when opened in chrome or firefox. Is there a css style that does the same thing as mix-blend-mode that works in edge?

Comment: Just to verify is your Edge up to date? Looks like only the chromium versions support it if I'm not mistaken, that large jump in version numbers is reflective of the chromium version of Edge.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code or the code from the moz link to the question itself. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the MS Edge legacy browser for making this test.

[mix-blend-mode](https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode) is not supported in the MS Edge legacy browser.

This is the reason that it is not working in the MS Edge legacy browser.

I suggest you try to make a test with the new [MS Edge Chromium](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge?&OCID=AID2001283_SEM) browser. mix-blend-mode is well supported in it.

Example:

```css
.container {
  padding: 15px;
 background-color: skyblue;
}

.img1 {
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
}
.img2 {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.img3 {
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}
.img4 {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/N0jVsWnX/img1.png" class="img1" width="300" height="300">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/N0jVsWnX/img1.png" class="img2" width="300" height="300">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/N0jVsWnX/img1.png" class="img3" width="300" height="300">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/N0jVsWnX/img1.png" class="img4" width="300" height="300">

</div>
```

Output in the MS Edge Chromium browser:

[image]